# Overwriting xml file #2

Tags: c#, xml

I'm trying to edit an xml and then save it with the same name.

I have the following code:

```
public int ModifyFile(string xmlpath, string option, int returnCode)
{
   XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
   xmlDoc.Load(xmlpath);
   XmlNode parentNode = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
   if (option.Equals("delete"))
      {
          returnCode = DeleteTag(parentNode, "identity", returnCode);
      }

      xmlDoc.Save(xmlpath);

      return returnCode;
 }


 public int DeleteTag(XmlNode root, string deleteName, int returnCode)
 {
     foreach (XmlNode node in root.ChildNodes)
     {
         if (node.Name == deleteName)
         {
             root.RemoveChild(node);
             returnCode = 1;
         }
         else
         {
             returnCode = DeleteTag(node, deleteName, returnCode);
         }
     }
     return returnCode;
 }
```

I'm getting "The process cannot access the file 'c:\temp\testfile.xml' because it is being used by another process" when it executes xmlDoc.Save(path).

How would I be able to save testfile.xml with the changes made?  I need to keep the path and name the same.

```
public static bool hasIdentityTag(string path)
{
    bool isTextPresent = false;
    if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        XmlTextReader rdrXml = new XmlTextReader(path);

        do
        {
            switch (rdrXml.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Element:
                    if (rdrXml.Name.Equals("identity"))
                    {
                        isTextPresent = true;
                        rdrXml.Close();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        } while (rdrXml.Read());
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The file {0} could not be located", path);
    }

    return isTextPresent;
}
```

Comment: Are you by-chance looking at this file using excel?  If so, make sure its closed while trying to run this code.

Comment: you're code worked perfectly for me - any chance your file gets locked before you call this procedures?

Comment: You can try to monitor access to the file using sysinternal process monitor: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what tags are for.

Comment: FYI, `new XmlTextReader()` has been deprecated since .NET 2.0. You should use `using (XmlReader rdrXml = XmlReader.Create(path)){...}`

Comment: John, will do. Thanks for the info.  Got it working now. Error in logic with my do... while loop.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to save the new XML to a temporary file, close the XmlDocument and dispose of the object, then move the temporary file back to the right place.

Comment: XmlDocument shouldn't be keeping the file open, so I wouldn't expect this to change anything.

Comment: Shouldn't... I was only suggesting that trying that may shed some light on the situation.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this re-write using LinqToXml:

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(xmlpath);
bool modified = false;
try
{
    switch(option)
    {
        case "delete":
            var toDelete = root.Descendants("identity").ToArray();
            foreach(XElement x in toDelete)
            {
                x.Remove();
                modified = true;
                returnCode = 1;
            }
            break;
    }
}
finally
{
    if(modified)
        root.Save(xmlpath);
}
return returnCode;
```

Answer (score -1):

How about loading the `XmlDocument` from a `Stream` instead of by file name? If you still encounter errors, this would indicate that something outside of your method/process is blocking the save.

Try rewriting the`ModifyFile` method like this:

```
public int ModifyFile(string xmlpath, string option, int returnCode)
{
   var fs = File.Open(xmlpath);

   XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
   xmlDoc.Load(fs);  // use the stream, not file name
   fs.Close(); // now close the stream... file should not be locked from this point 

   XmlNode parentNode = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
   if (option.Equals("delete"))
      {
          returnCode = DeleteTag(parentNode, "identity", returnCode);
      }

      xmlDoc.Save(path);

      return returnCode;
 }
```

Comment: That being said, `xmlDoc.Load(xmlpath)` (using a string file name) will open, read, and close the file; no need to switch to using a stream just for managing the close.

Comment: LOL, I don't think using a `Close` call merits a -1, but that's my own opinion...

Comment: My concern was that the code in the OP shows that he may be having this very problem elsewhere (`hasIdentityTag` does not always close the file). In addition (my second comment), this does not resolve any issues because `xmlDoc.Load(string)` already closes the file that it opens internally.